# Realm RLMObject attributesForProperty

Tags: ios, swift, realm

i'm fresh with using realm db. I took a look into realm documentation and I found a RLMObject class method 
`attributesForProperty:`

and I don't understand what is it doing.

Can you explain me when I can and need to use it.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite this method in your entity classes, which inherit from `RLMObject` to specify property-wise additional attributes, which influence the schema and behavior of your database. At the moment, the only choice you have is wether or not a property is indexed.

Assume you have a model class like in the docs:

```
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSInteger age;
@property NSString *name;
@end
```

### With v0.91.0 and above:

Since the release of [0.91.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0910-release-notes-2015-03-10), it is [easier to define indexed properties](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/935). If you want to have the `name` column indexed, then you're able to do that, by overwriting the class method like here.

```
+ (NSArray *)indexedProperties {
    return @[@"age", @"name"];
}
```

### Until v0.91.0:

Prior this release, you were able to specify your indexed columns like below:

```
+ (RLMPropertyAttributes)attributesForProperty:(NSString *)propertyName {
    RLMPropertyAttributes attributes = [super attributesForProperty:propertyName];
    if ([propertyName isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        attributes |= RLMPropertyAttributeIndexed;
    }
    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: Should be `return @[@"age", @"name"];`

Comment: Fixed and updated to latest minor release. Thanks for pointing out, but feel free to edit. ;)